# How to create metaclasses with dynamically named bases?

Tags: python-3.x, oop

here is my code:

```
class Tb(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name
    def foo(self):
        return 0

class Tb1(Tb):
    def foo(self):
        return 1

met=type('Tb1', (Tb1,), {})
a=met('aaa')

print(a.foo())
```

Is there any way to use dynamically named bases here:`met=type('Tb1', (Tb1,), {})` like `met=type('Tb1', (STRING_CLASS_NAME OR? ,), {})`

Answer (score -1):

I found an answer:

```
met=type('Tb1', (eval('Tb1'),), {})
```

Comment: Don't use `eval()`. You could just use `base = (Tb1,)` somewhere (and `type(name, base, {})`, or if you must use strings, see the duplicate.

Comment: I need a string value (dynamic), so I can't use your variant.

Comment: Yes, which is why I pointed to the duplicate.